# Google API Server to server authentication PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts, google-shopping-api

This problem is driving my round the bend - i have created a google service account  as per the instructions on this page

https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/quickstart

and i have my .json file

I have download the google api library from git and written the following PHP

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=content-api-key.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content');

$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$response = $httpClient->get('https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/********/accounts');

print_r($response);
```

Where i replace ***** is my merchant id.

How no matter what i try i can't connect and get the following error.

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
(
    [reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Unauthorized
    [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 401
    [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [Vary] => Array
                (
                    [0] => X-Origin
                    [1] => Origin,Accept-Encoding
                )

            [WWW-Authenticate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token
                )
```

This is my last resort. I have the account set-up for domain wide delegation.

Any help?

Jon

Comment: did you Grant the service account access to your merchant account

Comment: yes that i have done that

Answer (score 0):

> Unauthorized

Means that the account that you are authenticating with does not have access to do what you are trying to do.

**Service account**

What you need to remember is that a service account is not you.  It is also not the account that created it on the developer console.  A service account a dummy user it has its on drive account calendar account and you can share it access with your `Merchant Account`

**Service account perauthorization**

Make sure that you have followed [Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/how-tos/service-accounts) to set up your service accounts access.

> In the Merchant account add a new user take the service account email address and add that.
>
> 1. Add the new service account as a user to your Merchant Center account. If you are a third party developer, you will need to have your client do this step for you.
> 2. Go to your Merchant Center account.
> 3. Go to the 'Users' list in the settings of your Merchant Center account.
> 4. Click the + button, and use the service account ID as the email address for the new user.
> 5. If you did not take note of the service account ID earlier, go to the Service Accounts administration page and select the project you created.
> 6. Specify User access and Email notifications, note that use of the Accounts service requires Admin access. Add service account user page screenshot.
> 7. Click on the blue box to the left of Cancel. You will be returned to the list of users, and the service account ID should be listed with the chosen user role(s).
> 8. Repeat the process for all other service accounts you want to add.
> 9. View existing service account users by going to the Users tab. These will be users with an email address ending in 'gserviceaccount.com'.